# HDD randomly turns off and then on

Tags: hard-drive, sata, power-management

I have problem with my SATA HDD - it shutdowns itself from ocassionally, and then almost immediately turns back on again. It's system drive and the only one in my PC. I've disabled turning hdd off in Windows, SATA Aggresive Link Power Management in UEFI is also disabled, I turned this: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/177819-ahci-link-power-management-enable-hipm-dipm.html to Active too, but without effect. Also, in Intel Rapid Storage software LPM is disabled as well. SATA cables are OK, drive itself also, because it works well on another PC (with older mobo that doesn't have LPM feature). Power cable is OK too - DVD drive works perfectly on the very same plug. I don't know what to do next and it's pretty important for me, because this "feature" will quickly wear my HDD out.

My motherboard is Asrock Z87 Pro4, HDD is Samsung HD103SJ, OS is Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove that registry hack for starters. Also, update your Intel RST drivers.

How long has this been occurring, did it just begin recently, or has it been happening for the life of the drive? You may want to check the SMART status of it to see if it's in good health.

On some Dells, there's a BIOS option for "HDD Performance", with the choices of Bypass/Quiet/Performance. Interestingly, setting it to Performance actually caused the heads to park periodically, causing stutter in my games. Setting it to Bypass (the default, do-nothing setting) caused everything to work fine. You may want to review your HDD/SATA-related settings and set them to the defaults, or set them to the settings that you think would provide the least interference from the various systems between your drive and Windows.

You can also Google for a program called QuietHDD, which will set the AAM/APM values on your hard drive to your choosing (set them to the max: 254/255. This will disable these features).

Comment: It begun just when I changed my motherboard (in fact, I changed almost everything). Thanks for tip, I reviewed all of SATA related options and disabled them, additionally in Windows power management I set turning off HDD from Never to 9999999 (or so) minutes and now everything seems to work fine, at least for now.

PS I constantly monitor my HDD with CrystalDiskInfo :)